# Best regression method for ratio of two binomial processes as response.

Tags: multiple-regression

I have a situation where I have two binomial responses (A out of X and B out of Y). I have a binary categorical predictor C with a multilevel categorical covariate D. I basically want to find a way of doing the following regression

(A/X / B/Y) ~ C + D while ideally not losing information by simply taking the ratio of A/X and B/Y .

What regression methods are useful for this situation? (I'd prefer something with an R implementation).

Comment: What is your goal? Can you describe the practical context?

Comment: The context is I am looking at a process (C) across different cancer types (D) that can hypothetically affect two independent types of mutations (A and B are mutually exclusive, and so are the total number of possibilities for A and B). The objective is to figure out if differences in C predict differences in both A and B simultaneously after adjusting for the fact differences can exist between D.